# Enterprise distribution prompt message says (null) would like to install {app name}

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

[image]

This is popup that come after hitting on server url.

I uploaded a Enterprise distribution iOS build on a server.Now when we try to download build then following pop up came.I want to replace null field to "[my domain name]".

I got a link on stack overflow for similar problem-

[Ad-Hoc distribution prompt message says (null) would like to install {app name}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267987/ad-hoc-distribution-prompt-message-says-null-would-like-to-install-app-name)

But in my case problem is arise in both cases either go through (Download) email  or directly browse to a webpage which includes the link(server url where build had been uploaded).

Please suggest me solution.
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I resolved this issue.

Issue arise because we use single slace after `http:/` in web page where give **.plist path**.

i.e.

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http:/pathToYourServer/folder/applicationName.plist"> here </a>
```

Now changed, it become-:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://pathToYourServer/folder/applicationName.plist"> here </a>
```

In instalation prompt domain name take first parameter between :// and /. So carefull when write url.

Answer (score 2):

@Deepak's Answer solves the issue:

> `<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http:/pathToYourServer/folder/applicationName.plist"> here </a>`
>
> VS
>
> `<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://pathToYourServer/folder/applicationName.plist"> here </a>`

However be aware that there is a bug in Outlook that does not allow "//" in hyperlinks [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101555/double-slashes-in-urls-in-outlook) It is worth noting that you can construct the link in another email program and then send it to outlook. (At the time of this post I lack the rep to add this as a comment)

If you are willing to host a small page to redirect the user to the itms protocol this solution also works (if the redirect is modified): [Redirect on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-an-html-page/5411601#5411601)

Comment: Note: I now have sufficient reputation to add comments on non-self posts, however since this was upvoted and it does add some new contributions I will leave this post.

Answer (score 0):

It's because actual ipa resource file is not available into wireless distribution link. So I think it's configure wrongly the wireless ad hoc distribution link.

Comment: Nope dear... ipa is available.I am able to download and use this build. My problem is only Null.I want replace null to My Domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You must be trying to download the .ipa directly?

Archive and distribute the application and it will generate two files - one would be the .ipa and another would be .plist.

Now, create an html page on server and place it on server with this html:

```
<html>
<body>
Some text about your app:
<a  href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://pathToYourServer/folder/applicationName.plist">here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So, when user will tap on "here" then it will directly download the app on device.

Make sure to look at my hyperlink because it contains "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&" followed by path to plist file on your server.

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Reno Jones

Comment: Thank u Jones for your valuable suggestion...
I did same but problem is not solved Null come in Place off domain name.
Could u tell me which parameter is responsible for showing domain name?